# how to extract data into a file from snowflake table?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to extract data from snowflake table into a file.
The size of the extracted file is limited to 100MB by default.

Because of the limit on file size the last record of the file is split and some columns are going to next file.

Is there a way to limit the data extraction by number of records in the file instead of filesize?

Comment: Do you mean that some of the *rows* are going into the other file? seems strange if the columns are being split across files.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using a COPY statement, You can use the MAX_FILE_SIZE option to increase the file size to a 5GB max instead. (by setting it to 5000000000)

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#copy-options-copyoptions

Example:

```
copy into @mystage/myfile.csv.gz from mytable
file_format = (type=csv compression='gzip')
single = true
max_file_size=4900000000
```

I don't think there's a way to specify a number of rows per file in the copy syntax, although you can use a filter or a limit/fetch clause in your query to control the number of records that way.